# Visual C++ 2010: argv[0] is full path in debug mode, but only .exe name in release mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, argv, working-directory

In Visual Studio 2010 C++, I am reading argv[0] to get the working directory.

In debug mode it is definitely showing the full path of the directory and the exe file name itself (as expected)

In release mode it ONLY has the program .exe name, rather than the full working path.

1. why?
2. How to get working directory?

Comment: I should probably be using the GetCurrentDirectory function for Windows

Comment: For some reason both GetCurrentDirectory and GetModuleFileName are causing access violations.

Comment: LPWSTR whatever = (LPWSTR)"";
 int bytes = GetModuleFileName(NULL, whatever, 4096);

access violation

Comment: @Peter, `whatever` is pointing to a string literal of length `0` instead of a stack or heap-allocated buffer of at least length `4096`. Therefore, what happens when `GetModuleFileName()` tries to write to the buffer is not pretty.

Comment: You have to allocate enough space in whatever to allow the result string to be plugged in there. You are telling the API that there is 4096 bytes of space but allocating 1 char (the empty string, which includes its terminating NULL). I would also post your original `argv` code (in your question via an edit) since this is a pretty fundamental misunderstanding, perhaps there was something similarly wrong there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSVC will place the command used to launch the executable into `argv[0]` - this has nothing to do with the current working directory.

For example, if the command used to launch `foo.exe` is:

- `foo`, and the executable i found by searching the path, `argv[0]` will be `foo`
- `c:\foos-dir\foo`, (the path will is not searched) `argv[0]` will be `c:\foos-dir\foo`
- `foo.exe`, argv[0] will be `foo.exe`

etc.

You should probably get the current working directory using [the Win32 `GetCurrentDirectory()` API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934.aspx) or [the `_getcwd()` runtime function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf98bd4y.aspx).

Here's a short example using `GetCurrentDirectory()`:

```
TCHAR buffer[128];           
DWORD const buffer_chars = sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]);

DWORD result = GetCurrentDirectory( buffer_chars, buffer);

if ((result == 0) || (result >= buffer_chars)) {
    puts("problem getting the working directory");        
    exit(1);
}

printf( "Current working directory: %s\n", buffer);
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use GetCurrentDirectory and failed. When I do the following it gives me access violation: 

 LPWSTR whatever = (LPWSTR)"";
 int ret = GetCurrentDirectory(4096, whatever);

Comment: Your `whatever` pointer is pointing to a buffer that's not modifiable (it's a string literal) much less not having anything to do with a size of `4096`. I'll update the answer with a short example of using `GetCurrentDirectory()`.

Comment: You should probably use MAX_PATH instead of hardcoding 128.

Also, Visual C++ defines _countof() to determine the size of static arrays. (Saves you the buffer/buffer[0] syntax.)